# vs2010 + ReSharper6 = SLOW Javascript. Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Happens few minutes after opening a .aspx file with 250+ lines of JS code with many comments. When I'm editing JS - One core become 100% loaded and performance is like 1 letter per second. When i'm reopening the file - it starts to perform well for some time, but slows down again recently... How to fix it?

Environment: vs2010 + sp1
Additional software - Resharper6 (faced same issue with 5th version)

Hardware: C2Q9550 + 8Gb RAM

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper has a bunch of [features / improvements for Javascript](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#JavaScript) code. I guess some of the improvements were... suboptimal. It will be doing a lot of parsing and checking in the background while you type, that can take a reasonable amount of CPU time.

You may also find that your machine is just not powerful enough to run the newer version - i was running one of the beta builds of v6 but had to uninstall it due to performance issues, and that is on a multicore machine. Obviously different people will have different experiences, but personally i would not run it on a lower spec machine.

Comment: Agreed, my rig is a monster but still chokes with Resharper sometimes. I live without it these days and use a combination of VSCommands and some other extensions.

Comment: Firstly, I faced same problem with v5, but he is much less featured in terms of JS-intellisence. Secondly, there are similar issue with c# intellisence during debug, that is simply about breakpoints removing... I'm hoping to find similar trick here.